# Pascal's Triangle output alignment

Tags: alignment, output, pascal, pascals-triangle

So I've come up with the code to the values of the triangle itself. What I'm currently strugling is how to aligne/center the values that are printed. I tried many things but, I could use some help now. If anyone has an idea how this can be done feel free to share! Thank you

```
Program Tri_pas;
Uses Crt;
Var
    linha,ordem,a,b: byte;  


Function fat(X: byte): real; // factorial
Var fat1:  real;
Begin

  fat1:=1;  
  If X <= 1 Then  
    fat:=1
  Else
  Begin
    Repeat
      fat1:=(fat1 * X);
      X:=(X - 1);
    Until X <= 1;
    fat:=fat1;
  End;

End;



Procedure nCp(n,p: byte);  //Combinations
Var
    i: byte;
    nCp: real;
Begin

  If n < 1 Then
    n:=0  
  Else
    n:=(n-1);

  For i:=0 to n do    
  Begin
    writeln;
    For p:=0 to i do  
    Begin
      nCp:= fat(i) / (fat(p) * fat(i - p));    //  mathematic formula for the combinations      
      Write(nCp:1:0,' ');
    End;
  End;

End;


{ Main Programa  }

Begin

  Write('Insert a line(1 -> n) :  ');
  Readln(linha);
  nCp(linha,ordem);
  readln;  

End.
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add appropriate number of empty spaces before strings. Note that I used double-spaces, and changed placeholder size to 4 (3+1) to make better formatting.

```
For p := 1 to (n - i) do
  Write('  ');

For p:=0 to i do
Begin
  nCp:= fat(i) / (fat(p) * fat(i - p));    //  mathematic formula for the combinations
  Write(nCp:3:0,' ');
End;
```

P.S. There are more effective ways to calculate Ncr in reasonable range without real numbers.